VisualStudioでOfficeアプリケーションのようなリボンメニューを持ったアプリ開発はテンプレート等用意されていますか？
PowerpointやExcel等、OfficeアプリケーションのようなUIのアプリ開発をしたい場合に、テンプレートやフレームワーク、もしくはリボンメニュー等のコンポーネントはあるのでしょうか？
Win10(64bit),VisualStudio 2019 ,日本語環境を利用しています。
C#のWinFormsプロジェクトでFormにボタンやテキストボックスを追加したり、タブでページを切り替えるようなことは出来そうなのですが、以下のようなメニューのUIは、非常に難しそうで、テンプレート的なものや便利なコンポーネントがあれば、アドバイス頂けないでしょうか。(そもそも、そんなものは無かったり、C++ならあるとかでもありがたいです。)
イメージは以下のように部分です。


MFCプロジェクトの場合には新規作成時のウィザードコードの生成で「ユーザーインターフェース」の項目の「コマンドバー」で「(通常の)メニュー」「ツールバー」「リボンーバー」のいずれかが選択できます。これで「リボンバー(リボンコントロール)」を選択してビルドし、起動後「Windows7」スタイルを選択した場合の見てくれは以下の通りです。
VS2022で作成しました。また、生成されたコードのみです。参考までに。


WPF(Windows Presentation Foundation) でアプリを開発することで、System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon 名前空間に用意されている各コントロールを利用できます。
WPF では、ロジック部分は C# ですが、UI 部分は、XAML といった XML ベースの言語で記述します。
以下は、.NET 8 ベースの WPF でのリボンのコード例です。(Visual Studio 2022 を使用)
<Window x:Class="WpfApp001.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp001"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Ribbon SelectedIndex="1">
            <RibbonTab Header="ファイル">                
            </RibbonTab>
            <RibbonTab Header="ホーム">
                <RibbonGroup Header="クリップ ボード">
                    <RibbonMenuButton Label="貼り付け" LargeImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_object_160_s512_f_object_160_0nbg.png">
                        <RibbonMenuItem Header="メニュー 01" ImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_object_160_s512_f_object_160_0nbg.png" />
                        <RibbonMenuItem Header="メニュー 02" ImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_object_160_s512_f_object_160_0nbg.png" />
                    </RibbonMenuButton>
                    <RibbonButton Label="切り取り" SmallImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_object_167_s512_f_object_167_0nbg.png"/>
                    <RibbonButton Label="ボタン" SmallImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_business_97_s512_f_business_97_0nbg.png"  />
                    <RibbonButton Label="ボタン" SmallImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_business_93_s512_f_business_93_0nbg.png"  />                    
                </RibbonGroup>
                <RibbonGroup Header="フォント">
                    <RibbonButton Label="フォント" LargeImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_business_91_s512_f_business_91_0nbg.png"/>
                    <RibbonComboBox IsEditable="True">
                        <RibbonGallery SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectedValue="Abyssinian" MaxColumnCount="1">
                            <RibbonGalleryCategory>
                                <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Abyssinian" Foreground="Green" />
                                <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Japanese Bobtail" Foreground="Blue" />
                                <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Sphinx" Foreground="Orange" />
                            </RibbonGalleryCategory>                            
                        </RibbonGallery>
                    </RibbonComboBox>
                    <RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
                        <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_business_14_s512_f_business_14_0nbg.png"/>
                        <RibbonMenuButton SmallImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_business_18_s512_f_business_18_0nbg.png">
                            <RibbonMenuItem Header="メニュー 01" ImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_object_160_s512_f_object_160_0nbg.png" />
                            <RibbonMenuItem Header="メニュー 02" ImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_object_160_s512_f_object_160_0nbg.png" />
                        </RibbonMenuButton>
                        <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_business_34_s512_f_business_34_0nbg.png"/>
                    </RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
                </RibbonGroup>
                <RibbonGroup Header="配置">
                    <RibbonButton Label="配置" LargeImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_object_111_s512_f_object_111_0nbg.png"/>
                </RibbonGroup>
                <RibbonGroup Header="数値">
                    <RibbonButton Label="数値" LargeImageSource="/Assets/Images/f_f_object_111_s512_f_object_111_1nbg.png"/>
                </RibbonGroup>
            </RibbonTab>
            <RibbonTab Header="挿入">
            </RibbonTab>
            <RibbonTab Header="データ">
            </RibbonTab>
        </Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>

このように記述すると、以下のような画面になります。

ただし、Windows 7 ライクな見た目となることに注意ください。スクリーンショットは、Windows 11 上で取得しました。
各アイコンは、以下のサイトのものを使用させていただきました。

http://flat-icon-design.com/

